# Compound Indexes Order in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Let's say I have the following document schema:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(...),
  name: "Kevin",
  weight: 500,
  hobby: "scala",
  favoriteFood : "chicken",
  pet: "parrot",
  favoriteMovie : "Diehard"
}
```

If I create a compound index on `name-weight`, I will be able to specify a strict parameter (name == "Kevin"), and a `range` on weight (between 50 and 200). However, I would not be able to do the reverse: specify a weight and give a "range" of names.

Of course compound index **order** matters where a range query is involved.

If only **exact** queries will be used (example: name == "Kevin", weight == 100, hobby == "C++"), then does the order actually matter for compound indexes?

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#cursor.explain

Comment: could you elaborate? I've used the `explain()` command, but I don't follow.

Comment: `explain` is how you answer these sort of questions, like as described in Philipp's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have an exact query, the order should not matter. But when you want to be sure, the [`.explain()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) method on database cursors is your friend. It can tell you which indexes are used and how they are used when you perform a query in the mongo shell.

Important fields of the document returned by explain are:

- **indexOnly**: when it's true, the query was completely covered by the index
- **n** and **nScanned**: The first one tells you the number of found documents, the second how many documents had to be examined because the indexes couldn't sort them out. The latter shouldn't be notably higher than the first.
- **millis**: number of milliseconds the query took to perform

Comment: very informative. Why do you say `the order **should** not matter`?

Comment: @Kevin Because re-arranging the order of the find-arguments is an optimization task so trivial the database should be able to do it itself.